# How to resolve 'mediaType' must not be empty error in Spring 3.0 MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How to resolve `mediaType` must not be empty error in Spring 3.0 MVC? One of our requirement we want to implement the "Support Universal Links" for mobile app:

The file path should be: `http://localhost:9080/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` When I request the URL `https://localhost:9080/.well-known/apple-app-site-association` We are getting the below error:

Error:

```
[5/7/18 10:54:38:776 EDT] 00000125 SystemOut     O 2018-05-07 10:54:38,757 ERROR PageController - Exception while processing request for: /.well-known/apple-app-site-association
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'mediaType' must not be empty
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasLength(Assert.java:136) ~[spring-core-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:687) ~[spring-web-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.fallbackForContentProvider(StaticContentInterceptor.java:79) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.StaticContentInterceptor.preHandle(StaticContentInterceptor.java:111) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.5.0.jar:1.5.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:914) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) ~[spring-webmvc-3.1.4.RELEASE.jar:3.1.4.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:575) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668) [javax.j2ee.servlet.jar:na]
```

**My Controller:**

```
package com.sdl.webapp.main.controller;

import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.WebRequestContext;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.Localization;
import com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationResolver;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class AdminController
{
  private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AdminController.class);
  private String successView;
  @Autowired
  private WebRequestContext webRequestContext;
  @Autowired
  private LocalizationResolver localizationResolver;

  public AdminController() {}

  @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/.well-known/apple-app-site-association", headers="content-type=application/json", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
  public String getHeaders(@RequestHeader(value="Content-Type", required=false, defaultValue="application/json") String ContentType, @RequestHeader(value="Accept", defaultValue="application/json") String accept)
  {
    Localization localization = webRequestContext.getLocalization();

    LOG.trace("ContentType : " + ContentType);

    return localization.getPath() + "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `PageController`? If you created it, show its code.

Answer (score 0):

In your request mapping for "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association" , you are specifying a request header parameter of "Content-Type", however you are not supplying one with your request.

try a method signature of:

```
public String getHeaders(@RequestHeader(value="Content-Type", required=false) String ContentType)
```

or

```
public String getHeaders(@RequestHeader(value="Content-Type", defaultValue="some value") String ContentType)
```

Possible elements for the [RequestHeader](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestHeader.html) annotation are defaultValue, name, required and value.

Answer (score 0):

Add produce type to `@RequestMapping()`

example :

```
produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE
produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE
produces = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE}
```

Comment: insted of this `produces = "application/json"` use this `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE`